# Can I delete old downvoted questions that I edited but which were never upvoted, so I don't get banned?

Tags: support, edits, down-votes, post-ban

I have old down-voted questions that are (3-4 months old). Can I delete them?

I already updated most of those down-voted questions, but the votes on them didn't change.

Some of those question are down-voted for no reason like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082594/how-to-register-a-registeroutparameter-that-is-a-number-used-for-a-primary-key-w, or this one [How to populate a simple table with thymeleaf in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942358/populate-a-simple-table-with-thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc).

Now every time that I ask a question I get a warning that I'm going to be banned if I don't edit those questions, but since I already edited most of them, what should I do now? I can't wait forever to someone to upvote my questions since they are 3-4 months old and I have a lot of new questions that I want to ask since I'm working with new languages and frameworks etc.

Comment: Just a comment: you might have to learn proper English capitalization for your questions to be taken more seriously. E.g., start a question's title with a capital letter, and capitalize "I", at the very least. Ending phrases with appropriate punctuation would do a lot as well. Impressions matter...

Comment: Deleting questions is usually worse for your banned status. It also means that if it is deleted it can never be improved and start getting upvotes.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at what Patrick and I have done to this question and apply it to your other questions.

Answer (score 13):

You can technically delete the first question, it hasn't been answered so the system allows you to.

But remember that by doing so you keep getting close to a question ban. This question is only 7 days old, so its deletion will certainly count against you. Although this depends on your deletion rate/quality questions history on the site.

The second question is much older but you cannot delete it since it has an upvoted answer, that you accepted. Deleting it would waste the user that took time to read, understand and give an appropriate answer to it. For this reason, you should not be able to find any "delete" button below it.

See also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/176533)

Comment: i have 18 downvotes in total is that too bad? what would happens if i ignore the warning and create another question and this question is downvoted, would i get banned forever or just for a period of time

Comment: Yes @stackUser2000 that is bad and you're likely close to a question ban.

Comment: @stackUser2000 I don't think the exact details are public, that is to make it harder to game the system. I think your best bet would be to edit the question to improve it, and if that doesn't work, try asking for advice in meta on how to improve it. I'm sure someone will help you. :)

Comment: mmm ok, do you mean that it is allowed to create a new question here in Meta post the link of the question and ask for people to help me improve it, or that would give me downvote here in meta?

Comment: @stackUser2000 I meant the site specific meta, so Meta StackOverflow in this case.

Comment: @stackUser2000 If you want people to help you, you need to make a good faith effort.  Read the site's FAQ, spend some time fixing your questions, and ask about a specific question you want an answer to.  Most of all, *be receptive*.  People are usually willing to give advice, but they're not going to like something that just asks them to fix your question for you.

Comment: yeah i know i have edited already most of my downvote questions, and the ones i posted are some  examples, in some question i posted the solution that worked for me and pointed the user that help me to get to that solution but since they are old question and there are no popular i dont think that they are going to get upvoted, but i can try to ask in that site, can you please give me the link to that Meta site i can't find it, also english is not firts language so this make it more difficult.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: alright, i'm going to show how i have edited my questions  in meta.stackoverflow and see if they are edited in the right way, thanks for the quick support friend.